# MVC Jquery Validation in Model Dialog Not Displaying Summary

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have the following Jquery code in a function that loads a partial view and shows it in a dialog:

```
ysjs.openCreateDialog = function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/yourthings/Create/',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
            $('#create-modal').html(result).dialog({
                width: 700,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Create": function () {
                        $("#create-usr").validate();
                        if (!$("#create-usr").valid()) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    },
                    Cancel: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            }).dialog('open');
        },
    });
};
```

In my partial view I also force the jquery validation to reparse the DOM like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        //allow the validation framework to re-prase the DOM
        jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse();
    });
</script>
```

When I click the `Create` button the form seems to be correctly invalidated as a breakpoint on the `return false` gets hit in the firebug script view.

All other validation on the web site functions perfectly, so I'm not missing files or settings to actually make unobtrusive validation work but there is obviously some problem in this situation where the summary info is never shown.

If I place this same partial directly on the page, all the validation occurs as expected and show the messages in the UI.

What can I try to make sure the validaton messages are shown to the user?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how interesting this is or if it's expected behaviour but I have fixed this by changing:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse();
```

to:

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#create-usr');
```

Specifying the exact form to parse now shows the validation summary correctly inside the form in the dialog.